# What is the correct rxjs operator in case of nested subscription with if statement

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 subscription in an angular/typescript project.

These 2 subscription subscribe to each of their own observable `A` and `B` that is in outside of the component and in the service file.

Some times `A` change and `B` maybe not be change based on some component action  and vice versa.
However normally `B` changes after `A` changes in another component

Furthermore, `B` must do thing after checking the correct value of `A` . Therefore all I can think of is a nested subscription with an if statement like below.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.A = this.serviceX.a.subscribe(
      data =>{ 
        this.temp = data;
        if(data=='correct'){
            this.B = this.serviceX.b.subscribe(
                beta => {
                    console.log('Sure'+this.temp);
                }
            )
        }
      }
    )
}
```

While it works? But I have seen other post saying its not a good approach. So I tried `combineLatest` and `forkJoin`. But it seems they only works if both observable changes. And will not be called if one of the observable don't change at all. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So now all I can think of is seperate subscription and subscribe them one after another like below.

```
this.A = this.serviceX.a.subscribe(
  data =>{ 
    this.temp = data ;
  }
)
this.B = this.serviceX.b.subscribe(
  beta =>{ 
    if(this.temp=='correct'){
        console.log('Sure'+this.temp)
    }
  }
)
```

But Im very concern I am doing it wrongly and making an unstable iteration.
What exactly is the rxjs operator that I can use to make sure B subscription only subscribe after subscription A is done changing(However A maybe not be changed some time)? And eventually making the whole procedure more robust?

Comment: How/where are you using `this.A` and `this. B`?

Comment: `this.A` and `this.B` is only declared so that I can `unsubscribe()` them later on.

Comment: What about `this.temp`? Is it only used to do the check for B? Where/how do you actually use the values obtained from A and B?

Comment: Yes `this.temp` is only used to do the check for `B`.
I use the value obtained from `A` and `B` to modify another variable in the same class. Problem is `B` must wait for `A` to finish, had `A` have any changes for correct answer. However in some case `A` may not change at all and only `B` is changed.

Comment: Your comment above shows very convoluted logic which is not clear in your original question. You will therefore struggle to get a good specific answer as you can see by the variance of existing answers plus my now deleted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribing inside a subscribe-handler can get messy and I believe it can and should always be avoided. Your basic workflow - as I understood your code - is this:

1. retrieve data from `serviceX.a`
2. store data as side effect
3. if data satifies some condition, retrieve data from `serviceX.b`
4. actual subscribe handler

Now you can lookup an appropriate operator for each step. Here's how I'd do it:

```
this.serviceX.a.pipe(                 // 1 - load from a
  tap(data => this.temp = data),      // 2 - side effect
  filter(data => data == 'correct'),  // 3a - if
  concatMap(() => this.serviceX.b)    // 3b - load from b
).subscribe((beta) => 
  console.log('Sure' + this.temp)     // 4 - actual subscribe
);
```

---

Note 1: You need only one subscription here.

Note 2: Depending on your use case you might want to replace [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) with [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap), [`exhaustMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap) or [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap).

Note 3: the usage of `temp` is quite dangerous here. Depending on which `*map`-operator you choose you could create a race-condition. While you wait for an emission of `serviceX.b` `serviceX.a` could already emit the next value and overwrite `temp`. If the only reason for `temp` is to store the result from `serviceX.a`, you should go with this solution instead:
[Is there an operator that lets me keep the initial value from a subscription after executing ,, switchMap"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740872/is-there-an-operator-that-lets-me-keep-the-initial-value-from-a-subscription-aft)

Comment: Just want to confirm, sometimes `A` may not be change and thus no `next()` operation, emitting all that kind of stuff, you sure `B` will still run, if only `B` have change something?

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn No it won't. Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. You said "Some times A change and B maybe not be [...]", but you also said "Furthermore, B must do thing after checking the correct value of A" (I interpret B runs _after_ A). Now it's not really clear to me what should happen in which order. Both can change, but B needs to check the value of A. So what should happen if A doesn't emit? What should B check? And how do you check if A does _not_ emit, or if it's mabye just emitting _after_ B because of bad luck?

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn tldr; I would be happy to propose a solution, but I see that I didn't fully understand your question. We might need more details and you should work out a plan when what is supposed to happen :)

Comment: 1. `A` emits, `B` 'may' not emits and the operation ends there.

2. Now if after `A` emits, `B` also emits, then `B` must wait for `A` to finished the emission so `A` will return the final answer.

3. Also, after `A` emits and the `B` emits, `B` could be emits again without `A` emits anything.

Thus, there are that 'sometimes may happen sometimes don't confusion.'
Does this makes my question more clear?

Comment: I would say `B` must emits after `A`, since logically user can only access `A` before `B`. At least from the routing point of view. So once user click link `A`, A is register and emits. Then based on value emitted by `A`, `B` may also emits. Though `B` may emits many times without `A` emits anything, since `A` is already emitted. Thus I can't figure out how I can use filter rxjs operator.

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn To be honest, this seems to be a rather confusing design. My answer should work, if your second comment is true and `B` can only emit after `A`. Sometimes it's helpful to use `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` to handle late subscriptions, hope you get it to work ;)

Comment: Yes, the thing is, it works fine if I make them both BehaviorSubject, it works fine. I just wonder if there are any operator that is better.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for `flatMap`, you can map multi subscriptions, each `flatMap` should return it own `Observable` and only subscribe at end.

```
this.serviceX.a.pipe(flatMap(data => {
  this.temp = data;
  if (data == 'correct') {
    return this.serviceX.b.pipe(
      flatMap(beta => {
        this.temp2 = beta;
        console.log('Sure' + this.temp);
        return this.serviceX.c.pipe(map(delta => {
          this.temp3 = delta;
          console.log('Sure' + this.temp2);
          return delta;
        }));
      }));
  }
})).subscribe(delta => {
  console.log('Complete all subscriptions');
});
```

Comment: `flatMap` was deprecated and renamed to `mergeMap`: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/flatMap

Answer (score 0):

Call a `subscribe` inside another subscribe is a badpractice, because you broke the stream and start with another stream (In your example the subscriber inside is never destroyed, this could cause memory problems, you create a new subscriber B every time a stream enter in A, and this.B.Unsubscribe destroy only the last one).

Then you need to continue to manage your Stream with a `mergeMap` or a `switchMap` operator and call only one Subscribe at the end.

For filter your stream, you can use the `filter` operator.

```
this.serviceX.a.pipe(                 
  filter((data: any) => data == 'correct'),  
  switchMap((value: any) => this.serviceX.b)     
)
.subscribe((value: any) => 
  console.log('Sure' + this.temp);     
);
```

After that you have only 1 subscriber that you need Unsubscribe.